# Why am I getting `Invalid VNode type: Symbol("Fragment") (symbol) ` when trying to use Vue3/Vuetify3

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have the following...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Caw Caw</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.0.0-beta.11/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is a test</h1>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.0.0-beta.11/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="src/index.mjs"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
import App from "./App.vue";
const { createApp } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify

const vuetify = createVuetify()

createApp(App)
  .use(vuetify)
  .mount('#app');
```

```
<template>
  <h1>Now Vue is working</h1>
  <v-btn>Test Button</v-btn>
</template>
<script setup>
</script>
```

Before I added the `v-btn` tag everything worked. Afterwards I get...

> resolveComponent can only be used in render() or setup().

> Invalid VNode type: Symbol("Fragment") (symbol)
> at

What am I missing?

**Update**

Also I am using vite to test if that matters.

A functioning example can be found here...

https://github.com/purejgleason/example-vue-vite/pull/3

Main works and you can see the Vue message the branch fails as described.

I also confirmed both the node_modules and the CDN are Vue 3.2.39.

**Rabbit Hole**

I also tried to use Rollup instead but the problem appears to be with this line...

```
import { ref, onBeforeUnmount, watch, readonly, Fragment, computed, toRef, getCurrentInstance as getCurrentInstance$1, unref, provide, inject, shallowRef, shallowReactive, toRaw, watchEffect, effectScope, defineComponent as defineComponent$1, capitalize, camelize, h, onDeactivated, onActivated, reactive, onMounted, createVNode, toRefs, TransitionGroup, Transition, mergeProps, onBeforeMount, nextTick, withDirectives, resolveDirective, vShow, isRef, resolveDynamicComponent, onScopeDispose, warn, toHandlers, Teleport, vModelDynamic, cloneVNode, createTextVNode, onBeforeUpdate, vModelText } from 'vue';
```

it would work if this line was something like...

```
const = { ref, onBeforeUnmount, watch, readonly, Fragment, computed, toRef, getCurrentInstance as getCurrentInstance$1, unref, provide, inject, shallowRef, shallowReactive, toRaw, watchEffect, effectScope, defineComponent as defineComponent$1, capitalize, camelize, h, onDeactivated, onActivated, reactive, onMounted, createVNode, toRefs, TransitionGroup, Transition, mergeProps, onBeforeMount, nextTick, withDirectives, resolveDirective, vShow, isRef, resolveDynamicComponent, onScopeDispose, warn, toHandlers, Teleport, vModelDynamic, cloneVNode, createTextVNode, onBeforeUpdate, vModelText } = Vue;
```

**Rabbit Hole 2**

I looked and noticed that the version in the version in the Vite plugin is slightly different...

`"vuetify": "^3.0.0-beta.4"`

So I changed to

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.37/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.0.0-beta.4/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

But I still see the issue

Comment: How did you setup your project?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . This depends on your setup, which is unknown. The error would happen if you used multiple Vue copies. You generally shouldn't use raw modules with Vue like `<script type="module" src="src/index.mjs">`. The app needs to be built

Comment: @EstusFlask Also the example matches those at these links...

https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#using-vue-from-cdn

https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#cdn

Comment: The repo is not workable, `vite` command will fail with an error. There is no mention of `<script type="module" src="src/index.mjs">` in these docs. It looks like you have some unconventional setup without a clear reason. Don't use Vue CDN unless it serves a specific purpose. As I said, this error can appear when there are Vue copies. This is totally possible when one of them is global one and another is imported one

Comment: Also I have a specific reason for wanting to use the CDN version. I will debug the version in Node Modules though thanks for the lead

Comment: @EstusFlask I have a version using rollup to compile the Vue templates and that has other issues. I guess the question becomes how do I use Vue templates with a CDN?

Comment: You can't, at least in a normal way. From the docs linked above, `When using Vue from a CDN, there is no "build step" involved`. End of the story. If you need to use global Vue for some reason, this may be XY problem, consider reasking the question with your case explained instead of addressing a wrong solution